# Stop div element from auto resize with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have a div element that is say 500px that contains an image file that is say 490px. Every time I set the image from display:none to display:inline, the div resizes. How do I prevent this?

I'm using d3 to append the element. Could have anything to do with it?

Edit: This worked:

```
#your_div {
     width: 500px;
     min-width: 500px;
}
```

But my image only resizes from the bottom now.

Comment: Does your image have padding/margins?  Does the div?  Can we see some code?

Comment: Any solution for the image resizes only from the bottom when I change its height?

Comment: @Anonymous Hard to understand without a jsfiddle or more code provided.

Comment: When I set the height property of the image, the image only becomes smaller from the bottom and not form the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `min-width: 500px` on the div?

```
#your_div {
     width: 500px;
     min-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `width: 500px` if you don't want it to expand too